# Does TypeScript allow object literals without commas between properties?

Tags: typescript, plunker

I was looking at [the documentation for `ng-bootstrap`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown) and noticed that [one of their examples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/app/components/dropdown/demos/manual/plnkr.html) leaves out a comma in an object-literal definition.  (I can't link directly to the files in a Plunker, but it's line 30 of `src/app.ts`.)

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, JsonpModule, NgbModule.forRoot()], 
  declarations: [App, NgbdDropdownManual]
  bootstrap: [App]
}) 
export class AppModule {}
```

This led me to play around with the Plunker, and it turns out you can remove all the commas in the object declarations and the code still compiles and runs -- try adding `console.log({a:1 b:2})` to see what I mean.

Is this formally supported in all TypeScript, or is it an artifact of the way the code is compiled and run in this specific example?

Comment: line 30 in src/app.ts for me is this `declarations: [App, NgbdDropdownManual]` It's just an array.

Comment: @toskv yes but there is no comma at the end of the line.

Comment: ah, noticed it.. check my answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's most likely a result of the fact that when transpiling tsc will insert missing punctuation marks.

for example

```
let x = {
  a: 2 b: 4
}
```

gets compiled to:

```
var x = {
   a: 2, b: 4
};
```

At the same time a compilation warning is issued telling you that **,** is expected.

While this seems to be working I wouldn't rely on it since it seems to be nothing more than unintended consequence.

You can see this example in the playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=let%20x%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%202%20b%3A%204%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: Your Playground example link loads the default Playground page for me -- maybe double check your link syntax?  Anyway, I'm new to TypeScript but as long as I can treat warnings as errors in my compiler, this doesn't seem too bad.  Thanks!

Comment: I fixed the link